# JAXB unmarshalling дочерний элемент

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Имеется xml файл следующего содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:getRBGObjectListResponse
    xmlns:ns4="http://zakupki.gov.ru/fz44/https"
    xmlns:ns2="http://zakupki.gov.ru/fz44/ws/priz"
    xmlns:ns3="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/base/1"
    xmlns:ns5="http://zakupki.gov.ru/eruz/ws/elacts">
    <objectsInfo>
        <objectInfo>
            <documentUid>12345</documentUid>
            <documentKind>bankGuarantee</documentKind>
            <status>P</status>
            <publishDate>2021-04-26T09:55:07.000+03:00</publishDate>
            <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
            <regNumber>54321</regNumber>
            <schemeVersion>11.1</schemeVersion>
            <extPartnerType>VSRZ</extPartnerType>
        </objectInfo>
        <objectInfo>
            <documentUid>1233</documentUid>
            <documentKind>bankGuarantee</documentKind>
            <status>P</status>
            <publishDate>2222</publishDate>
            <versionNumber>1</versionNumber>
            <regNumber>858</regNumber>
            <schemeVersion>11.1</schemeVersion>
            <extPartnerType>VSRZ</extPartnerType>
        </objectInfo>
    </objectsInfo>
</ns4:getRBGObjectListResponse>
```

При попытке сделать анмаршаллинг содержимого JAXB создает экземпляры классов getRBGObjectListResponse и objectsInfo, но при этом не создает экземпляры класса objectInfo. Соответственно при вызове `objectsInfo.getObjectsInfo().toString()`получаю `ObjectsInfo{objectInfoList=null}`

***ObjectsInfo.java***

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "objectsInfo")
@XmlElement(name = "objectInfo")
private List<ObjectInfo> objectInfoList;

public ObjectsInfo() {
}

public ObjectsInfo(List<ObjectInfo> objectsInfo) {
    this.objectInfoList = objectsInfo;
}

public List<ObjectInfo> getObjectInfoList() {
    return objectInfoList;
}

public void setObjectInfoList(List<ObjectInfo> objectInfoList) {
    this.objectInfoList = objectInfoList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ObjectsInfo{" +
            "objectInfoList=" + objectInfoList +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ObjectsInfo that = (ObjectsInfo) o;
    return Objects.equals(objectInfoList, that.objectInfoList);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(objectInfoList);
}
```

}

***ObjectInfo.java***

```
package ru.rs.registerextract.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ObjectInfo {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement (name = "documentUid")
    private String documentId;
    @XmlElement (name = "documentKind")
    private String documentKind;
    @XmlElement (name = "status")
    private String status;
    @XmlElement (name = "publishDate")
    private String publishDate;
    @XmlElement (name = "versionNumber")
    private String versionNumber;
    @XmlElement (name = "regNumber")
    private String regNumber;
    @XmlElement (name = "schemeVersion")
    private String schemeVersion;
    @XmlElement (name = "extPartnerType")
    private String extPartnerType;

    public ObjectInfo() {
    }

    public ObjectInfo(String documentId, String documentKind, String status, String publishDate, String versionNumber, String regNumber, String schemeVersion, String extPartnerType) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
        this.documentKind = documentKind;
        this.status = status;
        this.publishDate = publishDate;
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
        this.schemeVersion = schemeVersion;
        this.extPartnerType = extPartnerType;
    }

    public String getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(String documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getDocumentKind() {
        return documentKind;
    }

    public void setDocumentKind(String documentKind) {
        this.documentKind = documentKind;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getPublishDate() {
        return publishDate;
    }

    public void setPublishDate(String publishDate) {
        this.publishDate = publishDate;
    }

    public String getVersionNumber() {
        return versionNumber;
    }

    public void setVersionNumber(String versionNumber) {
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

    public String getRegNumber() {
        return regNumber;
    }

    public void setRegNumber(String regNumber) {
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
    }

    public String getSchemeVersion() {
        return schemeVersion;
    }

    public void setSchemeVersion(String schemeVersion) {
        this.schemeVersion = schemeVersion;
    }

    public String getExtPartnerType() {
        return extPartnerType;
    }

    public void setExtPartnerType(String extPartnerType) {
        this.extPartnerType = extPartnerType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectInfo{" +
                "documentId='" + documentId + '\'' +
                ", documentKind='" + documentKind + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", publishDate='" + publishDate + '\'' +
                ", versionNumber='" + versionNumber + '\'' +
                ", regNumber='" + regNumber + '\'' +
                ", schemeVersion='" + schemeVersion + '\'' +
                ", extPartnerType='" + extPartnerType + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
private List<ObjectInfo> objectInfoList;
```

в классе **ObjectsInfo** аннотировал `@XmlElement(name = "objectInfo", required = true)`

поля в классе **ObjectInfo** аннотировал `@XmlElement(name = "documentUid", required = true)`